# How to set ios app BackgroundColor programmatically with Cordova?

Tags: ios, cordova

Cordova provides a "BackgroundColor" attribute which can be specified in the application's config.xml file. This sets the ios app background color. But, can this also be done programmatically from within the Cordova app?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution: cordova-plugin-webviewcolor

This plugin allows an app to programatically change the webview color.

Answer (score -1):

No you would need to use a plugin for that. Besides, what is the point of changing the color when you could simply change the body color of the webview?